# How to add inline style with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have this structure:

```
<div class="something1">
<div class="something2">
<div class="something3">
<div class="something4">
<div class="something5">
<div class="something6">
<div class="something7">
<div class="something8">
<div class="something9">
<article id="some-dynamical-id" class="something10">
<div class="something11">
<h2 class="something12">
<p class="post-meta"> ....
```

Now what i need is add inline style to this last element

I tried this:

```
<script>
document.getElementByClassName("post-meta").style.position = "absolute";
</script>
```

Comment: Its different question

Comment: I suspect there's an error in your console, because `getElementByClassName()` is invalid, but `getElementsByClassName()` **is** valid, and the "s" should indicate that it's not a single value, but a collection of sorts that must be iterated over.

Comment: Also with getElementsByClassName it doesnt work

Comment: `...it doesn't work`. How do you know? How did you attempted to implement this? Did you iterate over it as I suggested?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("post-meta").style.position = "absolute"; dont add inline style to classes

Comment: Again `getElementsByClassName()` is not a single value because you are getting element**s**. You'll need to iterate over each item in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementByClassName` is supposed to be `getElementsByClassName` and it returns an array so you can't apply style directly to it, you have to select the first or make a loop.

If you only have one element with this class, I suggest you to turn it into an `id` and use `getElementById`. Else, if it's the first element with this class, you can use `querySelector(".post-meta")` (or `getElementsByClassName("post-meta")[0]`)

Comment: I can't edit html and add ID. getElementsByClassName also doesnt work. There are more elements.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName("post-meta")[0]` works then if your `post-meta` element is the first element with that class. Since you can't edit your html

Comment: This effectively repeats what already has been mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return) and [in many many other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/10693845). From [answer]: "_avoid trying to answer questions which... ...have already been asked and answered many times before._"

Comment: getElementsByClassName("post-meta")[0] works for first one, but what if i need add style to all post-meta classes?

Comment: then you can do that inside a for loop and instead of 0 you use index
`getElementsByClassName("post-meta")[i]`

Comment: No, sadly with [i] all elements are without inline style

Comment: @Ivar Indeed I didn't think about it since the question can be answered fast, my bad

Comment: `elements = document.getElementsByClassName("post-meta");` save that in a variable like this then iterate thru your elements var 
`for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { elements[i].style.position = "absolute"; }`

https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/so7afg25/15/